# How to convert image format in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdata

I am working on universal application. On iPhone everything is working fine but when same functionality testing on iPad, my application gets crashed. When I am capturing image from camera I am converting that image to jpeg format, here is my code for converting image into jpeg format:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.7);//0.7
[imageData writeToFile:@"Select.jpeg" atomically:YES];
```

Image is UIImage. On iPhone its working fine but in iPad its crashes on second line and crash report is Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSFileManager fileSystemRepresentationWithPath:]: nil or empty path argument'.
 I searched it on google but not getting any solution or idea.

Comment: Did you try saving an another image and calling it name.ext~ipad ?

Answer (score 1):

your file name is Select.jpeg which is already present on that location.

you have to save your image with different name each time.

for best practice try to give image name with current time.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, its work for me

```
NSString *strImageName = @"select.jpg";
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",strImageName]];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:imagePath];

    if(fileExists)
    {
        BOOL remove = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:imagePath error:nil];
        if(remove)
        {
            NSLog(@"File removed...");
        }
    }
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgPreview, 0.7);
    [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```